# when iphone Device orientation is face up/down, can I tell if it´s landscape or portrait?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uideviceorientation

I got this code that if the device is in landscape left/right or upside down it rotates and shows another view controller. but if it´s in the orientation face up or face down, then how can I tell if it´s in landscape mode or portrait? cause I only want to rotate if it´s face up or down and in landscape mode

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];
        NSLog(@"orientation %d", orientation);
        if ((orientation == 2) || (orientation == 3) || (orientation == 4))
        {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayLandscapeView" sender:self];
            isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In UI code you usually should not depend on the *device orientation* but the *user interface orientation*. There's often a difference between them, for example when a view controller only supports portrait.

The most important difference for your case is that the interface orientation is never face up/down.

In your case you can just ask the view controller for the current user interface orientation: `self.interfaceOrientation`.

Your condition could be expressed somewhat like `if (deviceOrientation is face up/down and interfaceOrientation is landscape)`

Bear in mind that a device orientation landscape left means a user interface orientation landscape right.

Comment: @frédéric-adda has a Swift 3 / iOS 11 answer down below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46322727/1758224

Comment: that is weird, iOS 12 is here and this issue still isnt resolved. Also, they have deprecated the one which is working properly. :/

Comment: This is deprecated

Answer (score 16):

The `interfaceOrientation` property is deprecated since iOS 8.
And the helpers methods

```
UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)  
UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)
```

won't help either, because they return false when orientation is `.faceUp`.

So I ended checking this way:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var isPortrait: Bool {
        let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        switch orientation {
        case .portrait, .portraitUpsideDown:
            return true
        case .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight:
            return false
        default: // unknown or faceUp or faceDown
            guard let window = self.view.window else { return false }
            return window.frame.size.width < window.frame.size.height
        }
    }
}
```

This is in a UIViewController extension, so I can revert to comparing the screen width and height if everything else fails.

I use `window` because if the current ViewController is embedded in a container, it may not reflect the global iPad orientation.

Comment: In some places this is helpful. In others you need to check the size of the outer VC and compare it to the Window. One issue with this, however: you also need to return true if `isLandscape` is true. Thanks!

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation` is also deprecated now

Comment: I changed my method to check the orientation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, the `UIDeviceOrientation` is an enum which contains:

```
 UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
 UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,          
 UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
 UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,     
 UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,    
 UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,            
 UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
```

There are even two helpers:

```
UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)  
UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)
```

Just cmd on `UIDeviceOrientation` to show the headerfile where the enum is declared.

Comment: this does not work UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) 
i am passing UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(.faceup) it always give false

Answer (score 3):

There is one way to check it.

```
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation =[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

Use the first one to check if the device is in faceup and second one will tell you if the device is in portrait or landscape.