# How to change the device orientation to portrait when the current orientation is faceup or facedown

Tags: ios, cocoa, device-orientation

Is there a possible way to autorotate the device orientation to portrait when the current orientation of the device is faceup or facedown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742694/when-iphone-device-orientation-is-face-up-down-can-i-tell-if-its-landscape-or

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick to make the system refresh your controller orientation anytime you want:

```
[self presentViewController:[UIViewController new] animated:NO completion:NULL];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
```

This will call `supportedInterfaceOrientations` on your controller.

Just return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` when the device orientation is facing up or down and your controller's view will get adjusted accordingly.

---

Observe `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`s to use the trick when you receive the notification **and** it's a face up/down device orientation, as those orientation do not correspond to `UIInterfaceOrientation`s (and won't trigger `supportedInterfaceOrientations`).

Device and interface orientation definitions:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDeviceOrientation) {
    UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
    UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,            // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
    UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,  // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,       // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,      // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,              // Device oriented flat, face up
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown             // Device oriented flat, face down
};
```

Comment: where should i put that code. Sorry, i'm just new in iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

You don't change the orientation. Instead, you tell iOS which orientations you support, so when the user rotates the device, iOS will switch the UI orientation to one that your application supports. The UI orientation should only change when the user rotates the device.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your - (void)viewWillApper method

```
if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
 //do something;
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable or enable rotation of the screen in portrait mode by set an appropriate value in the project settings (Targets -> General -> Deployment Info section).

- mark the **Portrait** checkbox
- mark the **Upside Down** checkbox (this enable Upside Down animation)

or

- mark the **Portrait** checkbox
- unmark the **Upside Down** checkbox (this is only Upside mode)

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.view.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation`.

This value will be either `portrait`, `portraitUpsideDown`, `landscapeRight`, or `landscapeLeft`.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3198088-interfaceorientation) for documentation.