# Force change interface orientation between scenes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uiinterfaceorientation, skscene, skview

How can I force the game to switch from portrait (Scene 1) to landscape mode (HomeScene) in between scenes?

I have two scenes, Scene1 (which is portrait) and HomeScene (which is designed to be landscape)

I am calling this line from Scene 1.

```
-(void)gotoHome
{
    //Would like to change interface orientation here.

    HomeScene *scene = [HomeScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:scene];
}
```

Problem is, both the scenes are being rendered on the same view. How can I tell a viewController to rotate itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use this trick, and this will call `supportedInterfaceOrientations` on your controller.

```
[self presentViewController:[UIViewController new] animated:NO completion:NULL];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
```

A bit more in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22982364/242882

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really saved my life... I had to call the viewController from within the SKScene, and this worked wonderfully!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I am being able to go from Portrait to landscape, but not the other way round.